# ¿como dibujo un LineString desde el mapa y no desde el codigo?

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodejs, gson

quiero implementar una pagina web en donde pueda implementar el mapa y que el personal que usa la web pueda dibujar una linea en el mapa y que esas cordenadas automaticamente se represente en el codigo, quiero a hacer algo parecido a appinventor[image: imagen de app inventor]

quiero representar ese lineString en una pagina web, alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: eso ya es parte del npm, tendrías que leer la documentación de la misma que decidas usar

Comment: PadronRocha amigo tu disculpa pero no tengo mucho conocimiento de lo que es npm, depronto me podrias explicr mejor?

Comment: npm o Libería disculpame mi error, como vi la tag the nodejs creí que lo hacías con nodejs